# Why did Hila Tacorien end up in a pocket universe?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

Hila Tacorien, the human time traveler from the *Doctor Who* series 7 episode *Hide*, was trapped in a "parallel pocket universe" as a result of attempting to travel in time, and is described as a "pioneer" of her time.  Why did she fail to simply travel in time, and what caused her to enter the echo universe instead?

Comment: Related - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/in-the-doctor-who-episode-hide-how-does-the-alien-become-trapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found something that could possibly explain this... Since The Doctor stated she was a "Pioneer" that most likely meant that she was one of the first humans to attempt to use Time Travel Technology...  The Fifth Doctor actually explained Parallel Universes as such :

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Parallel_universe

> As the Fifth Doctor once explained to Turlough, parallel universes
>   were a specialised form of alternate universe — "alternative universes
>   [that existed] in parallel with each other" — but the terms weren't
>   complete synonyms. A parallel universe had no impact upon another
>   parallel universe; it was "separated only by a millisecond of time and
>   a nanometre of space, without ever having contact."

If somehow the device she was using malfunctioned it's possible that the device shunted her into that pocket parallel universe.

Comment: I think the Seventh Doctor also once described alternate universes as being "sideways in time," so crossing inter-universal boundaries does seem to be a form of time-travel.

Comment: This makes sense.  A malfunction could very well make her "bounce" off of time and into an echo.

Comment: Hell The Doctor has had moments where The Tardis went wonky too... lol